# to display data by date in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

to display data by date. For example there are several exam schedules, schedule 1 is past today's date and there is another schedule on the next date. well I want to display the next schedule.this is my code:

```
$id_user = g('id_user');
$user = DB::table('user')->where('id', $id_user)->first();
$divisi = $user->id_divisi;
$date =date('d-m-Y');
$schedule = DB::table('schedule')
                ->where('id_divisi', $divisi)
                ->orderBy('date_exam', 'DESC')
                ->get();

$response['api_status'] = 1;
$response['api_message'] = 'Success';
$response['api_authorization'] = 'You are in debug mode !';
$response['data'] = $schedule;
$response['api_http'] = 200;

response()->json($response)->send();
```

what do you use or if there are sample scripts in it? help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional constraint to your query to avoid getting past schedules. Try this:

```
$schedule = DB::table('schedule')
            ->where('id_divisi', $divisi)
            ->whereDate('date_exam', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))) // <----
            ->orderBy('date_exam', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

You can get more info about this in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses), also, [there is an article](https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/) that explains how this function works.